# How to link java class with layout resource file?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am having trouble connecting Java class file with Layout resource file in Android Studio.

I am trying to made an app so that when I press the button, it parses the website.

However pressing the button shows no reaction. I have a separate Java class for this button.

Instead, when I combine the parsing code with the main activity java class (which consists of auto created Navigation Drawer of Android Studio), the button works as intended. However if I do this, the Navigation Bar disappears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_lunch_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="ddalton.daltonapp.ParseMenu"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_lunch_menu"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="Parsed Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tex1"
    android:layout_weight="0.38" />

<Button
    android:text="Parse"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:id="@+id/but1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for my layout named content_lunch_menu.xml

```
package ddalton.daltonapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class ParseMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView texx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_lunch_menu);

    texx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex1);

    Button but=(Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("parse button pressed");
            new doit().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    String words;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("parsing");
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://daltonschool.kr/homeeng/04schoollife/040203schoollife.html").get();
            words=doc.text();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        texx.setText(words);
    }
}
}
```

This is java class for parsing, named ParseMenu.java

It seems like there seems to be some problem of java class not being able to be recognized, but I'm a beginner and I am not sure.

Any answers or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean, you want the change the previous UI with your layout?

Comment: I mean that the button (id of but1 in the code) does not work when I press the button. It does not bring any response.